# base64.b64decode function doesn't work properly, why?

Tags: python, base64, decode

I decode these two strings (see below) but test1 and test2 has the same result it means they're the same. Why? It seems that b64decode function cut the string after "==". What do I do wrong?

`test1 = base64.b64decode("IBFIgACAAIAAAA==Iq0yAACAMgAwMA==NzEI9AFkZEsegA==IHEINzdLS0sAAA==")
test2 = base64.b64decode("IBFIgACAAIAAAA==")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are concatenating multiple encoded strings together. That is not how encoding works.

Append the strings together before encoding them.

Or if you are trying to decode multiple encoded strings, loop over them:

```
encoded_strings = ["IBFIgACAAIAAAA==","Iq0yAACAMgAwMA==","NzEI9AFkZEsegA==","IHEINzdLS0sAAA=="] 

for i in encoded_strings:
    print(base64.b64decode(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its good to know why this happens and what "=" in this case means and the usecase of it in base64.

Your assumption that base64decode function cuts the string behind "==" is in some way correct, because the base64decoder is interpreting it as the end of your base64 String.

Its important to know how the "=" character works and that its more like a special character in base64 encoding and has no corresponding character which encodes it.

Just to give you a short overview and not going to deep into this Topic:

If base64encode function gets a String as Input to generate a base64 encoded String the Length of input String has to be dividable by 3. 
If its not, base64 is automaticaly adding the padding character "=" at the end of the base64 encoded String to tell the base64decoder function how much bytes were needed to fill the Input String to an dividable by 3 String and that he can decode the String correctly back to the original String.

So in your case the base64decoder sees your "=" character in your String "IBFIgACAAIAAAA==" and probably interpret this as the end of the base64 String.

**Conclusion**:

You will see the "=" character always at the end of a base64 String, if the string is not a multiple of 3, and its doesn't encode any character.